# Is this a correct usage of transients?

Tags: loops, data-structures, clojure, dynamic-arrays, mutable

In the talk ["Bootstrapping Clojure at Groupon" by Tyler Jennings](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/Bootstrapping-Clojure), from 25:14 to 28:24, he discusses two implementations of a `separate` function, both using transients:

```
(defn separate-fast-recur [pred coll]
  (loop [true-elements (transient [])
         false-elements (transient [])
         my-coll coll]
    (if (not (empty? my-coll))
      (let [curr (first my-coll)
            tail (rest my-coll)]
        (if (pred curr)
          (recur (conj! true-elements curr) false-elements tail)
          (recur true-elements (conj! false-elements curr) tail)))
      [(persistent! true-elements) (persistent! false-elements)])))

(defn separate-fast-doseq [pred coll]
  (let [true-elements (transient [])
        false-elements (transient [])]
    (doseq [curr coll]
      (if (pred curr)
        (conj! true-elements curr)
        (conj! false-elements curr)))
      [(persistent! true-elements) (persistent! false-elements)]))
```

(These are both copied verbatim, including the unidiomatic indentation in the last line of the second one.)

He notes that, in the benchmark he used, the first function above took 1.1 seconds while the second function above took 0.8 seconds, noting that the second is therefore superior to the first. However, according to the [Clojure documentation on transients](https://clojure.org/reference/transients):

> Note in particular that transients are not designed to be bashed in-place. You must capture and use the return value in the next call.

Thus it seems to me that this `separate-fast-doseq` function is incorrect. But I am having difficulty believing that it is incorrect, considering the nature of the rest of the talk.

**Is this `separate-fast-doseq` function a correct usage of transients? Why or why not?** (And if not, what is an example of it breaking?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second implementation is incorrect for exactly the reason you suspect. A transient collection is *permitted* to mutate itself for efficiency, but it is never *required* to, so any one of these `conj!` calls may return an object with a different identity. If that happens, then by discarding the result of `conj!`, the function you have pasted will behave incorrectly.

However, I cannot provide an example of it breaking. In the [current implementation of Clojure](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/c716a5a8802cc40a45fca8bbddb6c574b42e2a17/src/jvm/clojure/lang/PersistentVector.java#L577-L607), as it happens, `conj!` *does* always mutate itself in place. Note the unconditional `return this` at the end. Therefore, this function will behave as expected. However, it relies for its correctness on implementation details, which may change at any time.

For an example of a similar sort of operation which does break, try using a map instead of a vector:

```
(let [m (transient {})]
  (doseq [i (range 20)]
    (assoc! m i i))
  (count (persistent! m)))

8
```

Comment: Sounds to me like: Don't do this, it just happens to work and can break at any time.  "But it worked on my machine", never goes very far.